# Can I use empty with magic properties?

Tags: php

Quote from the [PHP documentation on overloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset):

> It is not possible to use overloaded properties in other language constructs than isset(). This means if empty() is called on an overloaded property, the overloaded method is not called.
>
> To workaround that limitation, the overloaded property must be copied into a local variable in the scope and then be handed to empty().

Does this really mean that I cannot use something like

```
if (empty($this->foobar))
```

in a class, where `$this->foobar` is a magic property, resolved through `__get()`, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I should add that I tested this and it *does* seem to work for me.

Comment: It resolves through `__isset()` firstly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement __isset() magic method in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242591/how-to-implement-isset-magic-method-in-php)

Comment: @mario: So the fact that it works correctly means I implemented my `__isset()` method correctly!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you override the `__isset` method as well. The reason the documentation is written as such is because you can't call `empty() or isset()` on the result of a method call.