# Why must objects that make use of __get() for dynamic properties also implement __isset()?

Tags: php, oop

I am studying how `array_column` works and I have read that if applying this function to an array of objects whose properties are private/protected, an implementation of both `__get` and `__isset` is needed. But I don't understand why `__isset` is used when `__get` itself can access these properties.

```
<?php

class Person{
    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __get($prop)
    {
        return $this->$prop;
    }

    public function __isset($prop) : bool
    {
        return isset($this->$prop);
    }
}

$people = [
    new Person('Fred'),
    new Person('Jane'),
    new Person('John'),
];

print_r(array_column($people, 'name'));
?>
```

[I have found this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803448/when-to-use-isset-and-when-to-use-get), but I didn't find an answer.

Comment: Because: 1. `__get()` on an un-set property will generate a notice, but just return NULL, and you're going to want to avoid that situation most times. 2. If your getters and setters use something more complex than object properties to store information you will need more complex `__isset()` logic.

Comment: What if i am sure that the property isset and removed the __isset, i will get an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects using `__get` do not require `__isset`.

The [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) function use `__isset` to check if should fetch `private` or `protected` property.

The point of using `__isset` prior to `__get` is to ensure that it should fetch **existing property** value.

It's equivalent of checking array value before using it:

```
// Initialize array with not fully expected data
$myArray = getValues();
if(isset($myArray['myColumn']))
{
    echo $myArray['myColumn'];
}
```

In your example class php would do for each `Person` instance something like this internally:

```
if($persion->__isset('name'))
{
    return $person->__get('name');
}
```

**NOTE:** Using `isset($this->$prop)` is a bad idea, as it will return false on `null` value!

Use [`property_exists`](http://php.net/property_exists) instead, ie:

```
public function __isset($prop) : bool
{
    return property_exists($this, $prop);
}
```

Comment: If array_column needs to access values, and the __get is present, which helps in accessing the protected/private properties, why __isset..

Comment: I've added more details

Answer (score 2):

After some thinking, i have found what convinces me, which is that the `array_column` function applies the `isset` function on each property, which needs the `__isset` magic method to be implemented into the class to be called whenever `isset()` is called on a protected/private property