# __set() and __get() not work with isset() and empty(). How solve?

Tags: php

having:

```
class foo {
    
    private $myproperty;
    
    public
    function __construct() {
        if (
            ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) &&
            ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE )
        ) {
            session_start();
        }
    
    public
    function __set( $name, $value ) {
        if ( property_exists( "foo", $name ) ) {
            $_SESSION[ $name ] = $value;
        }
    }
    
    public
    function __get( $name ) {
        if ( property_exists( "foo", $name ) ) {
            return $_SESSION[ $name ];
        }
    }
    
}
```

Doing:

```
$foo = new $foo();
$foo->myproperty = "value";
if ( isset ($foo->myproperty ) ) {
  echo "myproperty setted";
} else {
  echo "myproperty not setted"
}
```

Why return `"myproperty not setted"`? Same problem if i replace `isset` with  `empty`. Is a bug? If no, how i can fix it?

Comment: Have a read through [How to implement __isset() magic method in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242591/how-to-implement-isset-magic-method-in-php).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between isset() and \_\_isset()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227585/what-is-the-difference-between-isset-and-isset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the __isset() method. Here is an example:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    private $myproperty;

    public function __construct() {
        if (
            ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) &&
            ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE )
        ) {
            session_start();
        }
    }

    public function __set( $name, $value ) {
        if ( property_exists( "foo", $name ) ) {
            $_SESSION[ $name ] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __get( $name ) {
        if ( property_exists( "foo", $name ) ) {
            return $_SESSION[ $name ];
        }
    }
    
    public function __isset($propertyName){
        return isset($_SESSION[$propertyName]);
    }
}
        


$foo = new foo();
$foo->myproperty = "value";

if ( isset($foo->myproperty) ) {
  echo "myproperty setted";
} else {
  echo "myproperty not setted";
}
?>
```

Note that this way empty() will work too because internally it uses __isset().

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to check with `isset` when you already have magic [__GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) method on the class level and you are already implementing the same functionality. The second typo with your code is that class name is not `new $foo();` which should be rather just `new foo()`. However, I would recommend to **Title Case** for class names something like `class Foo`.

```
class Foo {

private $myproperty;


public function __construct() {
    if (
        ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) &&
        ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE )
    ) {
        session_start();
    }
}


public function __set( $name, $value ) {
    if ( property_exists( "foo", $name ) ) {
        $_SESSION[ $name ] = $value;
    }
}




  public function __get( $name ) {
        if ( property_exists( "foo", $name ) ) {
            return $_SESSION[ $name ];
        }
    }
   
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->myproperty = "value";
if ( $foo->myproperty  ) {
  echo "myproperty setted";
} else {
  echo "myproperty not setted";
}
```

Though if you're still looking on how to use `isset`, you can just add the following method to your `class`

```
public function __isset($name)
{
    return isset($_SESSION[$name]);
}
```